# Docker multistage build vs. keeping artifacts in git

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

My target container is a build environment container, so my team would build an app in a uniform environment.
This app doesn't necessarily run as a container - it runs on physical machine. The container is solely for building.

The app depends on third parties.
Some I can `apt-get install` with `Dockerfile` `RUN` command.
And some I must build myself because they require special building.

I was wondering which way is better.

1. Using [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) seems cool; Dockerfile for example:

```
From ubuntu:18.04 as third_party
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ...
ADD http://.../boost.tar.gz /
RUN tar boost.tar.gz && \
        ... && \
        make --prefix /boost_out ...

From ubuntu:18.04 as final
COPY --from=third_party /boost_out/ /usr/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ...
CMD ["bash"]
...
```

Pros:

- Automatically built when I build my final container
- Easy to change third party version (boost in this example)

Cons

- `ADD` command downloads ~100MB file each time, makes image build process slower
- I want to use `--cache-from` so I would be able to cache `third_party` and build from different docker host machine. Meaning I need to store ~1.6GB image in a docker registry. That's pretty heavy to pull/push.

On the other hand

2. I could just build boost (with this `third_party` image) and store its artifacts on some storage, `git` for example. It would take ~200MB which is better than storing 1.6GB image.

Pros:

- Smaller disc space

Cons:

- Cumbersome build

  - Manually build and push artifacts to git when changing boost version.
  - Somehow link Docker build and git to pull newest artifacts and `COPY` to the final image.

In both ways I need a `third_party` image that uniformly and automatically builds third parties. In `1.` the image bigger than `2.` that will contain just build tools, and not build artifacts.

Is this the trade-off?
`1.` is more automatic but consumes more disk space and push/pull time,
`2.` is cumbersome but consumes less disk space and push/pull time?

Are there any other virtues for any of these ways?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose changing your first attempt to something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as third_party
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ...
RUN wget http://.../boost.tar.gz -O /boost.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf boost.tar.gz && \
        ... && \
        make --prefix /boost_out ... && \
        find -name \*.o -delete && \
        rm /boost.tar.gz  # this is important!

From ubuntu:18.04 as final
COPY --from=third_party /boost_out/ /usr/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        ...
CMD ["bash"]
```

This way, you are paying for the download of boost only once (when building the image without a cache), and you do not pay for the storage/pull-time of the original tar-ed sources. Additionally, you should remove unneeded target files (`.o`?) from the build *in the same step* in which they are generated. Otherwise, they are stored and pulled as well.

If you are at liberty posting the whole `Dockerfile`, I'll gladly take a deeper look at it and give you some hints.

Comment: Are you actually saying `ADD` should never be used? Always use `RUN wget ...` instead? I could delete the whole extracted dir, including `*.o`, that's a good idea! But I'm not sure about deleting `rm /boost.tar.gz` - wouldn't it be nice to keep that in case the link breaks, or if I want to fetch the `third_party` image and do some manual building?

Comment: Yes, you should never use `ADD` with an URL, even Docker says so: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: My personal reason: It does not use the build cache (even with seemingly stable URLs): https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12361 To be fair, it's not a good idea to assume the file behind a URL never changes, so the design decision is reasonable.